# insert data to mysql fields empty

Tags: mysql, objective-c

Hi im trying to insert data to a mysql database. I get new content every time i click on save but the columns in the database don't get the text (From the textview and textfields).

```
    -(IBAction)save:(id)sender{    
    NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"location=%@",address.text,@"&long=%@",longitude.text,@"&lat=%@",lat.text,@"&texten=%@",texten.text];

    NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.info/projct/phpFile.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It works when i insert data to database by a webbrowser.

Comment: This was not related to xcode. And I do not think it is related to mysql neither. Aparently it is none of your business as app developer what persistant storage the php script uses - if any. Do you have a chance to debug what the php script actually receives?

Comment: You should urlencode address.text and texten.text. To be on the save side you could urlencode longitude.text and lat.text too, especially if those are user input data fields.

Comment: what i can see is that, the php file recives emptey parameters from the URL / Request @HermannKlecker

Comment: So the request is being sent and received but all data fields in $_POST are empty? Did you try to nslog rawStr?

Comment: And what is the contents of rawStr?

Comment: The content should be the text from 'texten.text' 'NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"location=%@",texten.text];' @HermannKlecker

Comment: I can see what it should be. What I asked is what it actually is when it is converted to NSData and added as body to the request.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that you are setting the request header to indicate that this is form-encoded data.  Without this, PHP will not populate `$_POST` superglobal automatically (also POSTed data will not be reflected in URL).  You might want to check `php://input` to see if you are actually getting the data:

You can do that like this:

```
$query_string = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($query_string);
```